# Printing only skip number 3,rest fine

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I have created a linked list, which prints the output just fine except only when the string `name` contains a single digit **`3`** .I also tried `fflush()` on `stdin` and `stdout`, without success.

The function:

```
  void disp(node *head)
     {
      while(head->next!=NULL)
      {
      printf("\n%d\n%d\n",head->roll,head->marks);
      puts(head->name);puts(head->add);
      head=head->next;
      }
      printf("\nlast::::%d\n%d\n",head->roll,head->marks);
      puts(head->name);puts(head->add);
     }
```

Also, why there is a need of extra printing statements, after the while loop? Why the loop `while(head->next!=NULL)` terminates on the second last node?

The code :

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

  typedef struct NODE
 {
 char *name,*add;
 int roll,marks;
 struct NODE *next;
 }node;

 void disp();

 int main()
 {
  node *head,*temp,*cur; int ch;

  head=(node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
  printf("enter roll marks name add\n");
  scanf("%d%d",&(head->roll),&(head->marks));
  fflush(stdin);fflush(stdout);
  gets(head->name);gets(head->add);
  head->next=NULL;
  temp=cur=head;

  while(1)
 {
  printf("enter more?y/n\n");
  ch=getche();
  if(ch=='n')break;
  temp=(node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
  printf("enter roll marks name add\n");
  scanf("%d%d",&(temp->roll),&(temp->marks));
  fflush(stdin);fflush(stdout);
  gets(temp->name);gets(temp->add);
  temp->next=NULL;
  cur->next=temp;
  cur=temp;
  }

  disp(head);
  getch();
  return 66;
 }

  void disp(node *head)
 {
  while(head->next!=NULL)
  {
  printf("\n%d\n%d\n",head->roll,head->marks);
  puts(head->name);puts(head->add);
  head=head->next;
  }
  printf("\nlast::::%d\n%d\n",head->roll,head->marks);
  puts(head->name);puts(head->add);
 }
```

Sorry for an old compiler : Turboc (sorry its a compulsion)

**UPDATE:**

here is the output sample as requested :

```
enter roll marks name add
1
2
3
4
enter more?y/n
yenter roll marks name add
5
6
7
8
enter more?y/n
n
1
2

4

last::::5
6
7
8
```

As we can see, number 3 is not displayed.

Comment: its unclear what you are asking, provide more details and some debug watch variable details.

Comment: Please do not call `fflush(stdin)`. It has undefined behaviour.

Comment: @fede1024 If I don't, I need to provide an extra input statement don't know the reason though.

Comment: Try with `scanf("%d%d\n",...`.

Comment: you can also use `getchar()` until you get an EOF

Comment: `gets(head->name)` ? where did you reserved memory for that pointer?

Comment: @fede1024  The o/p now is ::
1
2
4

last::::1
2

4

Comment: @Kira I think you were right, with an array it works fine.Wrong Assumptions.Well you can answer that.

Comment: @joey_rohan The malloc allocates enough memory for the structure (including the two pointers to char), but you never allocate space for the strings (and initialize the pointers)

Comment: @fede1024: `fflush(stdin)` has defined behaviour on systems using the MSVC runtime library (Windows; I'm not sure whether Turbo C uses the native runtime library, but I assume it probably does).  See the answers to [Using `fflush(stdin)`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2979209/using-fflushstdin) for more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pay attention:

1. "Also, why there is a need of extra printing statements, after the while loop? Why the loop while(head->next!=NULL) terminates on the second last node?"

--> Answer: Look at your `while()` condition: `head->next!=NULL`: means that you won't enter the `while` if the next node equals `NULL`. So, for the last node you'll won't enter the `while`, and won't print your things. You can change your logic in order to do it more nice.

1. Your main question:

--> Answer: Before I know really what's happening, you must pay attention: you do your `malloc` thing and allocates memory for each `node` of yours, `BUT!` you didn't allocate your `strings`. for each `node` you allocate, you need to allocate also `char *name,*add`. if you don't, when you do `gets(temp->name);gets(temp->add);` you're just messing with the memory - these pointers doesn't point on anything - it works magically and might don't work at other time/ other compiler. You must `malloc` these two `chars*` as well. If you don't want to mess with it, you can start with declaring them as

`char name[128], add[128];` - This way you don't have to allocate them - cause they are already allocated. You can start like this.

Comment: for head->next!=NULL, why last node will equal null? are not we talking about the address part of the node, but not the node itself?

Comment: reserving 128 bytes in advance would not save him from failing in the future, `gets` is a dangerous function and should not be used in newer programs, `fgets` should be used instead.

Comment: @joeyrohan, Look at your code, for each node, next will be equal `NULL`: `temp->next=NULL;`. (It's a good thing)

Comment: Even I get warnings its dangerous, but `fgets` works same as `gets` just provided the `stdout` thing?

Comment: @joeyrohan That's incorrect. While it is true that `fgets()` works similarly to `gets()`, the most important distinction between the two is that `fgets()` allows you to specify the maximum amount of input to accept. Since the `gets()` function does not provide this ability, it is always possible for someone to provide more input than your program is prepared to accept, this is called a "buffer overflow" and is a far-too-common cause of program failures and security breaches. It is for this reason that the `gets()` function is usually regarded as unsafe for any use, anywhere, ever.